# Vertical Spacing adjustment between different chapter's labels in the list of equations

Tags: latex

I am writing a thesis, where I had to include a list of equations (like a list of figures, tables, etc) in the Table of Contents (ToC). I followed the answer given [here](https://ipfs-sec.stackexchange.cloudflare-ipfs.com/tex/A/question/270611.html) and successfully added List of Equations to the ToC. But the problem is the vertical spacing between the different chapter's equation labels. I need to have a gap between two different chapter labels like in the default list of figures/tables. I am attaching the thesis.cls file that has default definitions for the list of figures/tables/symbols etc and also the list of figures and equations screenshot

In a nut-shell, list of equations of mine should like the list of figures in terms of format

[image: Image of list of equations]
[image: Image of list of figures]

Following is the minimal reproducible code for a list of equations

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\xpretocmd{\listofmyequations}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listequationsname}}{}{}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listofmyequations

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2 
\end{equation}
\myequations{Energy Equation}
\begin{equation}
F = ma 
\end{equation}
\myequations{Force equation}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{First section}
\begin{equation}
S = vt
\end{equation}
\myequations{displacement equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can patch the `\chapter` command like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof[chapter]{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\xpretocmd{\listofmyequations}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listequationsname}}{}{}

\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{equ}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listofmyequations

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2 
\end{equation}
\myequations{Energy Equation}
\begin{equation}
F = ma 
\end{equation}
\myequations{Force equation}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{First section}
\begin{equation}
S = vt
\end{equation}
\myequations{displacement equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I know manually only. Please add the following command at end of the each chapter `\addtocontents{equ}{\addvspace{1.2pc}}`. And regenerate the toc.